# Difference between new (float*)[] and new float*[]

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

What is the difference between: `new int*[]` and `new (int*)[]`:

```
int** pA = new int*[2] // returns a pointer to an array of pointers to int.

new (int*)[2] // what should this return ? Shouldn't it be same as the above.
```

Likewise,

```
float* pB1 = new float[3]; // compiles successfully.

float* pB2 = new (float)[3] //Gives an error. Shouln't it return an array of floats ?
```

But, the compiler says:

> ```
> A value of type 'float' cannot be used to initialize a value of type float* .
> ```

What am I missing here? I'm using VS2015 Community IDE.

Comment: you are requesting a placement new; the call is understood as a pointer passed to new; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

Comment: @OznOg, you should expand the comment to a full fledged answer.

Comment: Don't forget to use Standard Library containers like `std::vector` whenever possible and avoid manually allocating with `new`.

Answer (score 6):

```
float* pB1 = new float[3];
```

is allocating an array of float

```
float* pB2 = new (float)[3]
```

is asking to allocate an array of ?? in 'float' location (which is meaningless), that's the error you get.
This is the placement new syntax, see more info here [Difference between new (float*)[] and new float*[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46695598/c-difference-between-new-float-and-new-float#46695598) or http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new as pointed in comments

Comment: your answer contains a stack overflow